# Connect to remote nysql database from Heroku node app - works on localhost

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, heroku

my code is as this:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000
const mysql = require('mysql');

let mainData;

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'xx.xx.xx.xx',
  user     : 'zosimaia_dbm',
  password : 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  database : '............'
});

connection.connect();
connection.query('SELECT Name,Surname,YearOf,HomeAdCity_ID,Job_ID FROM graduates', (err,rows) => {
    if(err){ console.log(err)};

    console.log('Data received from Db:');
    console.log(rows[0].Name);
    mainData=rows;
});

connection.end(); 

app.all('/data', function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
    next();
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hey there!') )
//app.get('/test', (req, res) => res.send('Random test! '+ testData) )
app.get('/data', (req, res) => res.json(mainData) )

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`))
```

Everything is working fine on localhost:3000 but Heroku displays an **Application error** message. I have added the DATABASE_URL var as `mysql://zosimaia_dbm:.....@..../.....` on the app's page. I have added the app's URL and my localhost IP address to CPANEL Remote MySQL.

The logs containing lines such as:

```
{
2019-11-04T22:23:45.015109+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR',
2019-11-04T22:23:45.01511+00:00 app[web.1]: errno: 1045,
2019-11-04T22:23:45.015112+00:00 app[web.1]: sqlMessage: "Access denied for user 'zosimaia_dbm'@'ec2-54-74-62-252.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com' (using password: YES)",
2019-11-04T22:23:45.015114+00:00 app[web.1]: sqlState: '28000',
2019-11-04T22:23:45.015115+00:00 app[web.1]: fatal: true
2019-11-04T22:23:45.015116+00:00 app[web.1]: }
```

and

```
at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/"
```

Strange since I am using a hosting company - not amazonaws.com.

Thank you for any suggestions
Giannis